# Formatted SQL With PreConditions

Tags: liquibase

I'm on Liquibase Version: 2.0.1.

Is it possible to have pre-conditions in a formatted sql file? If so how?  An example would be appreciated.

I would like to do somthing like this but in sql formatted file.

```
 <preConditions onFail="WARN"> 
    <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">select count(*) from oldtable</sqlCheck> 
 </preConditions>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Specifying preconditions in a liquibase formatted sql file is now supported. Within a changeset definition, the preconditions may be specified using the following format (copied from the official docs):

```
--preconditions onFail:HALT onError:HALT
--precondition-sql-check expectedResult:0 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table
```

It is noted in the documentation that only the sql check precondition type is supported at this time.

Complete documentation is available [at the liquibase website](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html).

Answer (score 2):

**Outdated:** The feature has been added in latest Liquibase version. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27494608/256561 for up to date solution.

Unfortunately, the current `FormattedSql` parser does not support preconditions.

You could extend the default class with your own parser that would support it if you need, however. See http://liquibase.org/extensions

Comment: Is this still true? The latest docs (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html) show that it is possible, though I'm admittedly having trouble getting this to work.

Comment: It is no longer true. Preconditions should work fine with formatted sql now.

Comment: Verified. I was having trouble with them because the onFail action was incorrect :-)

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.